# angular-strap Select button property undefined

Tags: angular-strap

I get `TypeError` from angular-strap select button

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcons" data-html="1" data-multiple="1" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons" bs-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replaces bs-options with ng-options if you are using angular-strap less than 2.2.0